# How to use Powershell to grant Windows application or executable to use your network profile?

Tags: powershell, cmd

Powershell newbie here. I am learning Powershell (yes, I have been ignoring it all these years) as I have never needed this one particular need of mine. I have looked at PS tutorial sites and, of course, StackOverflow for any tips. Seems like my need is unique.

Short story, how do you execute an application (for example, notepad.exe) on a local machine to open a network shared file but the local machine has a generic logged-on user but the network share requires a privileged user (like mine) to open the file. I want the app/executable to inherit my credentials but not set the local machine itself. I want to run a local app/executable as if I logged on to the local machine with my credentials.

I have read PS can do this exact thing so I have been experimenting with Powershell command line:

```
start-process "[SOME APP].exe" -FilePath "\DIRECTORY\PATH\WHERE\APP\IS\LOCATED]"  -Credential (Get-Credential -Credential "DOMAIN\USERID")
```

I get an error prompt from the Powershell command line:

> start-process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The
>   system cannot find the file specified. At line:1 char:1
>   + start-process "[SOME APP].exe" -FilePath "[\DIRECTORY\PATH\WHERE\APP\IS\LOCATED] ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOp    erationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C
>   ommands.StartProcessCommand

I plan on using this Powershell script in my LabVIEW executable to assign the VI (virtual instrument) executable my own network login privilege to transfer files to/fro or modify a text file that resides in the network share.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Are you going to be the generic user logged in or physically in front of the machine while this runs? Is running the application remotely a possibility? If someone else is logged into the machine, I would not want to give generic user control to run this script. I would set up a service account or use some other JIT/JEA strategy if I am not in complete control of when this script executes. Otherwise, it sounds like a recipe for your credentials to be abused. I would like to help, but I don't want to offer a solution that has a bad security practice.

Comment: No the local machine is usually accessed with a generic user credential that has no network access. When I run this script, I will be granting the executable my network credential to sync a local folder to the remote (like logs, etc.)

Comment: Then the executable quits and the inherited credentials disposed of. No, I will  not be remotely executing the executable. The user will be in front of the local machine and the app will just ask his/her network credentials to perform the folder sync. If user does not have proper network access - the app will not be able to access the network share. Thanks for the security tip but I thought of this in advance that is why I am not "burning in" my access privilege in the LabVIEW application as it may be abused. I want the  user to enter his/her credential every single time.

Comment: Will all machines launch the same app? Is there a common working directory that you expect users to be in when launching the app as they will need to have access to that directory, e.g. c:\users\username?

Comment: I provided an answer as an example. I will need more information to understand what experience you are expecting.

Comment: Yes. Many test stations can and will run the same application but not at the same time as the operator (user) will go one station at a time uploading/syncing the test logs to the remote network share. After each run I expect the network credentials to be disposed of automatically (is this correct assumption?) when the executable quits or do I have to spin another Powershell script to do garbage collection? Thank you for your expert advice. I don't want my network credentials lingering after the user has finished the task (syncing the test reports and logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following. All you need to do is change the `$app` variable to the executable you want and save the script as a PS1 file. Someone can run it by right-clicking and selecting Run with PowerShell or opening a PowerShell console and typing in `path\scriptname.ps1`.

```
$App = "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe"
$Credentials = Get-Credential
$WorkingDir = Split-Path $app
$Exe = Split-Path $app -Leaf
Start-Process -FilePath $Exe -WorkingDirectory $WorkingDir -credential $Credentials
```

Comment: I adapted the above to LabVIEW code and worked as intended. Thank you very much for the tip!

Comment: Since there is no LabVIEW forum here, head over to NI Community to see the LV code adaptation of above.[NI Community](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Use-Powershell-to-grant-LabVIEW-executable-application-higher/m-p/3905766/highlight/false#M1108494)